# Trying to figure out the asymptotic density

Tags: limits, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisor-counting-function

Let $a>0$.

I have the following function $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R} $ defined in the following way:

\begin{equation}\label{km relation}
 f(m) = m +\lfloor a  m -  \tfrac{a }{2} +\tfrac12 \rfloor. 
\end{equation}

Now, define a `counting function' $A: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by
\begin{equation}\label{}
 A(x) = \sum_{\substack{a \in f(\mathbb{N}) \\ 1 \le a \le x}} 1.
\end{equation}

where $f(\mathbb{N})$ is the image of $\mathbb{N}$ under $f$.

What  is $\lim_{x \to \infty} \tfrac{A(x)}{x}$?

I think that it should be $\frac{1}{a+1}$, but since $a$ can be irrational, I can't seem to quite prove it- I get stuck.

Comment: Is it $A$ a set of integers, a function $A(x)$ or the resultant set of real numbers output by the $f(m)$ function when you input the set of natural numbers?? 

Comment: @JVGD Is it clearer now?

Comment: As a complement to reuns' answer, I'd like to point out that $f(m)$ is locally well-behaved and it allows for a shortcut. First observation: $f$ is strictly increasing. It's also easy to see that $f(z+1)=f(z)+a+1$ for all $z$ (integer or not). Another simple observation is that $f(m)$ is an integer, if and only if $m$ is an integer itself. So, considering any interval $[z,z+1)$, we can see that $f$ can only have 'caught' a single integer out of $a+1$. From there, it's easy to derive an asymptotic result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{f(n)}n=a+1,\qquad \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(A(x))}{x}=1$$

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(A(x))}{x}=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(A(x))}{A(x)}\frac{A(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to \infty} (a+1)\frac{A(x)}{x}$$